# Why dose PHP Mysqli_fetch_row work but not Mysqli_fetch_assoc on my server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I know a little about how to debug and deal with errors when using PHP. However, this one is an an anomaly.

After I successfully create a connection to my Mysql database via mysqli, I try to get the result from it.

```
if($result = $db->query($query)) {

$num_results = $result->num_rows;  
echo "<p> Number of books found: ".$num_results."</p>";
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();  //no problem if I use fetch_row
```

**The weird thing happens, the whole page collapses and the browser shows "the webpage can not be displayed".**

I try to identify the problem and replace the line "$row = $result->fetch_assoc();" with "$row = $result->fetch_row();" and it successfully fetch the result from database (I didn't show the above/below code here for the sake of brevity).

It turns out that "fetch_array" and "fetch_object" failed as well. The other part of coding works just fine once i comment it out. So i just wonder how could fetch_row works but "fetch_array/object/assoc" seems to make the whole page collapse (not just the function itself and there is no PHP error message as well).

Answer (score 0):

You don't see errors it's because you don't have enabled errors, I believe you are not using the right functions to call `fetch array` or `fetch association`, search in your class for the right function, as I believe `fetch_array()`, `fetch_assoc()` throws Fatal Error in php.

Search in your apache logs.

Try to add in your php file on top:

```
ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. It lies in the incompatibility of Mysql and PHP (version mismatch). I have no choice but reinstall the whole pack using Wamp. The code itself is just fine, that's why i simply can't find the problem. Thanks anyway!!!